# Use detach() to place each element after every other element in other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a little trouble writing a Javascript function that utilizes jquery detach() to move some elements to another div. My issue is that I would like to place each detached element in a specific place, after every other element in said div and I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to do this.

For example:

```
<div id="col-left">
 <li>Item One</li>
 <li>Item Three</li>
 <li>Item Five</li>
</div>

<div id="col-right">
 <li>Item Two</li>
 <li>Item Four</li>
 <li>Item Six</li>
</div>
```

Needs to become:

```
<div id="col-left">
 <li>Item One</li>
 <li>Item Two</li>
 <li>Item Three</li>
 <li>Item Four</li>
 <li>Item Five</li>
 <li>Item Six</li>
</div>
```

I've tried a couple things, including what's below, but it doesn't give expected results.

```
$("#col-right li").each(function() {
   $(this).detach().insertAfter("#col-left li:nth-child(2n)");
});
```

I know I need to target every other item in #col-left and insert $(this) after it but I'm not sure how to write that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By the way, your markup is incorrect. `<li>` elements must always be direct children of `<ul>` or `<ol>` containers.

Comment: @VisioN Hah! Nice catch. I didn't even notice that. So much for my reading comprehension.

Comment: @VisioN Thanks. I am well aware, but for example purposes, I used <li> as an element. In my real code, it's divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to store all the left `<li>`'s in a variable, and insert based on index:

```
var $originalLeft = $("#col-left li");
$("#col-right li").each(function(index, el) {
   $(this).insertAfter($originalLeft.eq(index));
});
```

Also note that `.detach` isn't necessary since `.insertAfter` will already do that.

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fcbtd5k/)**

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much.  Never have come across eq() before so this was a good learning experience, after looking it up.